# Associate Ids and names from a json with the itemonclicklistener?

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, onitemclicklistener

How do I associate the ids and names from a JSON file with the position parameter in onitemclicklistener in Android Studio?
I have a JSON data file containing ids and names and I want to retrieve them into a listview onTextChangedQuery in autocomplete search. I have done that but now I can't relate it to their respective position in OnItemClickListener.
This is the JSON file

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "26",
        "fullname": "Abbas",
        "address": "mingora"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "fullname": "shakeel",
        "address": "mingora"
    },
    {
        "id": "29",
        "fullname": "Fayaz",
        "address": "Odigram"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "fullname": "Fayaz",
        "address": "Odigram"
    },
    {
        "id": "31",
        "fullname": "m fayaz",
        "address": "odigram"
    }
]
```

The following is the code:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray DATA = Jobject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < DATA.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = DATA.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    name = jsonObject.getString("fullname");
                   // getting id from json

                     String newId = id;
                    int currentid = myids.length;
                    int newSize1 = currentid + 1;
                    String[] ArrayId = new String[newSize1];
                    for (int k = 0; k < currentid; k++) {
                        ArrayId[k] = myids[k];


                    }
                    ArrayId[newSize1 - 1] = newId;
                    myids = ArrayId;


                 //the following code adds new item to the array from the json object
                    String newItem = name;
                    int currentSize = contactList.length;
                    int newSize = currentSize + 1;
                    String[] tempArray = new String[newSize];
                    for (int j = 0; j < currentSize; j++) {

                        tempArray[j] = contactList[j];
                    }

                    tempArray[newSize - 1] = newItem;
                    contactList = tempArray;
                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BloodDonerActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView, contactList);

                    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {


   String userId = myids[pos];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //id of user on position
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where you pass the Array in Adapter???

Comment: Saurabh Vadhva now check it!

Comment: Firstly you have to use ArrayList instead of String Array. And you are using String Array then you have to create the another String array to store the values of Ids.And then you can get those ids using StringArrayNameForID[pos] into the onItemClick() method.